# Django4.0 админка и длинна названия поля

Tags: django

Вопрос такой, как проверить и обрезать ВСЕ дниные названия ВСЕХ полей в админке? В идиале хотелось бы реализовать такой механизм который будет считать длинну полей и если длина больше 30 символов, то будет после 30-го символа рисовать " ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MODELS.PY**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name='Назване поля',
        )

def __str__(self):
    short_name = (
        self.title[:40] +
        '..') if len(self.lead_guest_name) > 75 else self.lead_guest_name
    return f'{short_name}'
```